# QML: material accent on a button doesn't cover full area

Tags: qml, material-design

I applied a material theme to a button but, when the mouse passes on the button area the "accent" (not sure if it is the correct word) doesn't not enlight the full button but leaves a bar on the high and low part of the button (or a 1 pixel circle for round buttons).

This is my code

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15
import VenusView_UI 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height
    color: "#2a2929"
    radius: 0
    border.width: 4
    property bool rec_clicked: true
    property bool crop_clicked: true
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.BlueGray

    Rectangle {
        id: controlsbackground
        color: "#ffffff"
        radius: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: rec_video.bottom
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#434343"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#000000"
            }
            orientation: Gradient.Vertical
        }
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 4
        anchors.rightMargin: 4
        anchors.leftMargin: 4
        z: 0
        
        Button {
            id: cropButton
            width: 60
            height: 60
            visible: true
            text: ""
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: rec_controls.left
            anchors.rightMargin: 60
            flat: true
            highlighted: true
            
            Image {
                id: cropimage
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: crop_clicked ? "images/crop_button.png" : "images/crop-un_button.png"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }

            Connections {
                target: cropButton
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("play")
                    crop_clicked = !crop_clicked
                    cropimage.source = crop_clicked ? "images/crop_button.png" : "images/crop-un_button.png"
                }

            }
    }
}
```

I add some images to make it more clear:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The button is "colored" just when the mouses passes on it.

How could I solve it?